# Starting HTC camera in photo/video mode

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, htc-android

I am building an app that uses the device camera app to take photos or record videos. There is a single button in my app that starts the camera app, and does it using MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA intent. So far, on all non-HTC devices that I've tested, the camera app opens in the default mode in which I can switch between taking photos and recording videos, while on HTC devices I can only record videos. Is there any method of starting the camera app on HTC devices from another app in the same mode as when it is started from the launcher.

Comment: This might be a **stupid** question from me but: Does HTC have an entirely separate application for recording video? I don't think it uses the generic one like most OEM's do behind the scenes. I'm open to being wrong though.

Comment: The HTC camera app can both take photos and record videos when started from the launcher. However, when started from another app using the above Intent, it is only possible to record videos.

Comment: I was just remembering that HTC's video camera can take pictures, or even pictures out of the video stream itself, so I was wondering if their Video Recording app IS the camera or if they completely split the two apps out. In most cases the camera is just the camera with video / picture options. Just thinking out loud really. HTC are a PAIN for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far, on all non-HTC devices that I've tested, the camera app opens in the default mode in which I can switch between taking photos and recording videos

There are *thousands* of camera apps, both ones that are pre-installed or installed by users. Many may elect to support `INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA`. None are required to have a "default mode in which [the user] can switch between taking photos and recording videos". This is not a problem with HTC -- it is a problem with your expectations.

> Is there any method of starting the camera app on HTC devices from another app in the same mode as when it is started from the launcher.

Even if there is some undocumented, unsupported, unreliable, script-kiddie way to force this on some HTC devices, there are **many** other camera apps that will not offer such a means.

If you want that degree of control, write your own camera app.